# sql server invalid object name - but tables are listed in SSMS tables list

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am attempting to create a `Stored Procedure` for a newly created database. However the `SSMS` intellisense does not recognize more than half of the tables which have been created.

For example whilst in the left hand column under tables I have a table `dbo.Room`, when I type "`dbo.`" in the new query window, that table is not listed, in fact only 17 out of 37 tables are listed.

I can see no difference between the tables listed by intellisense and those not. If I manually type dbo.Room, it is underlined, with an error of

> Invalid Object Name 'dbo.Room'..

Have I missed something in setting up the tables?

UPDATE: I have tried refresh of the tables list (several times)

Comment: Answer that works: `[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]` [SO: Invalid Object Name sql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24621331/1608670)

Answer (score 924, accepted):

Try:

<kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>IntelliSense</kbd> -> <kbd>Refresh Local Cache</kbd>
or use the hotkey
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

This should refresh the data cached by Intellisense to provide typeahead support and pre-execution error detection.

NOTE: Your cursor must be in the query editor for the IntelliSense menu to be visible.

[image: SSMS Menu Entry: Edit - Intellisense - Refresh Local Cache]

Comment: Thanks, I suspect that this would have solved. I actually restarted SSMS and found that that solved. Probably should have done that in first place, but my initial thought was I had done something wrong in setup.

Comment: Does Intellisense/SSMS refresh itself periodically? Or must this always be a manual process? (I've got my guess based on SSMS in 2005, but one can always hope.)

Comment: unbelievable that in 2012 you need to do this. Couldn't they update Intellisense every few seconds automatically?

Comment: That may require hitting the database and pulling the table/view definitions every few seconds.

Comment: @jinglesthula Every few seconds might be much, but adding a new object/column seems fine to me.

Comment: NOTE: Your cursor must be in the query editor for the IntelliSense menu to be visible.

Comment: @jinglesthula: That would save *me* hitting the database server!

Comment: This doesn't appear to work on linked servers, though - at least, it didn't for me

Comment: Thanks, the refresh worked. It would be great if, at the least, IntelliSense would give you a light bulb like in Visual Studio to offer suggested fixes.

Comment: Short cut combo: Ctrl+Shift+R (SSMS 17)

Comment: This is crazy! The table was actually causing me problems with Linq within an application (not SSMS) that I was working on - returning weird results when it should have just been empty & causing exceptions. When I tried this in SMSS, the problem went away! Sorry to ruin the magic "666" upvotes but I have to add one just for that...

Comment: @thanos.a Is still valid in my version 17.6. You really should add a version number that this doesn't work in.

Comment: @IT Alex I have checked it in 18.4 and the menu is valid.

Comment: Works in v18.5 in 2020. They still don't auto update intellisense.

Comment: Thank you. Might be a setting somewhere to auto-update/refresh. Let me know anybody found that option.

Comment: In VS Code, you can also do CTRL+SHIFT+P and search for "MS SQL: Refresh Intellisense Cache" to refresh (assuming mssql extension is installed of course).

Comment: It works! I wonder why there is no clear error message or a simple suggestion by SMSS to make a refresh!

Comment: It's 2023, and we still need to do this: Version 18.12.1

Comment: Working in 2023, vs19.2. +1 for the image.

Answer (score 137):

Make sure that the selected DB is the one where the table is. I was running the Script on `Master`. In my case, I had to switch to `hr_db`.

[image]

Rookie mistake but, could help someone.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a rookie mistake to be honest, as whenever you reconnect the server it for some reason switches to "master" for no obvious reason. :)

Comment: If that were the case and the query did not fully qualify the table names, the code wouldn't execute. I believe the OP was describing false positive error detection when the problem you've described was not a contributing factor. (Certainly, I had already ruled out the possibility when I went searching and wound up here.)

Comment: Exactly my issue. There's no indication from SMS that it's changed the database context, or any other clue.

Comment: @ChrisRae: That's because `master` is set as the default database for your user login. Just change that using `sp_defaultdb` to another database to have the other database being selected in SSMS when you log in. (Can also be set in SSMS by `Security > Logins > your user login > Properties > Default database`)

Comment: Just to add to this. Make sure the table is referencing the same schema, i.e. "dbo." schema.

Answer (score 99):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> refreshes intellisense in management studio 2008 as well.

Comment: I don't have this feature ... when I press ctrl + shift + R nothing changes

Comment: @IbrahimAmer Your cursor must be in a query editor for the Intellisense menu option to be available. If the intellisense menu option is not available the shortcut will do nothing.

Comment: It also works for T-SQL in SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Answer (score 45):

once you create a new SQL Server object, your newly created object does not get updated in the IntelliSence Local Cache and due to this, it shows red line underneath that object. So you just need to refresh SSMS IntelliSence Local Cache and once you refresh it, `IntelliSence` will automatically add newly created object in the cache and the red line will disappear. try this

`Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`  or    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I don't have this feature ... when I press ctrl + shift + R nothing changes

Comment: @IbrahimAmer Your cursor must be in a query editor for the Intellisense menu option to be available. If the intellisense menu option is not available the shortcut will do nothing.

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the IntelliSense cache was listing object information for an entirely different database.  If I clicked the "New Query" button in SSMS, it would open a query to my default catalog on the server and that query editor would always only use that database.  Refreshing the cache didn't change anything.  Restarting SSMS didn't change anything.  Changing the database didn't change anything.

I ended up creating a query by right-clicking on the database I actually wanted to use and choosing "New Query" from that context menu.  *Now* SSMS uses the correct objects for IntelliSense.

Comment: USE datbaseName GO before query also works in setting up the context

Comment: @BehroozKarjoo Yeah, I tried that.  It doesn't always seem to work.  If I could reproduce it, I'd put it on Microsoft Connect or something.  I'm sure they'd mark it as WONTFIX or something equally irritating, but I'd report it.

Comment: Restart SSMS and right click new query worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Are you certain that the table in question exists?

Have you refreshed the table view in the Object Explorer? This can be done by right clicking the "tables" folder and pressing the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.

You may also need to reresh the Intellisense cache.

This can be done by following the menu route: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

Answer (score 7):

The solution is:

- Click menu Query,
- then click 'Change Database'.
- Select your appropriate database name.

That's it.

Answer (score 7):

Same problem with me when I used this syntax problem solved.

Syntax:

```
Use [YourDatabaseName]
Your Query Here
```

Answer (score 5):

Even after installing SP3 to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise this is still an "issue." <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> like everyone has been saying solved this problem for me.

Comment: I don't have this feature ... when I press ctrl + shift + R nothing changes

Comment: @IbrahimAmer Your cursor must be in a query editor for the Intellisense menu option to be available. If the intellisense menu option is not available the shortcut will do nothing.

Answer (score 4):

In azure data studio press "cmd+shift+p" and type "intellisense", then you will see an option to refresh intellisense cache.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this question has already been answered, however, I had a different solution:

If you are writing a script where you drop the tables without recreating them, those tables will show as missing if you try to reference them later on.

Note: This isn't going to happen with a script that is constantly ran, but sometimes it's easier to have a script with queries to reerence than to type them everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Solved for SSMS 2016.

Had a similar problem, but Intellisense was not in Edit menu.

What seemed to fix it was turning Intellisens on and off, right click on the SQL editor and click 'Intellisense Enabled'. Right click again on 'Intellisense Enabled' to turn it back on again. Ctr Q, I also does this.

This solved the problem, and also I know get the Intellisense on the Edit menu.

Answer (score 2):

did you try: right click the database, and click "refresh"

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, I am sure it is there, I can add records and modify etc.Just did a Select * from dbo.Room and whilst I still have the underline it outputted the contents of the table. I'm gonna try a reboot.

Comment: Refresh did not worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I just had to close SMSS and reopen it. I tried Refresh Local Cache and that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the problem with :
ODBC and SQL-Server-Authentication in ODBC
and
Firedac-Connection

Solution :
I had to set the Param MetaDefSchema to sqlserver username :
FDConnection1.Params.AddPair('MetaDefSchema', self.FDConnection1.Params.UserName);

The wikidoc sais :
MetaDefSchema=Default schema name. The Design time code >>excludes<< !! the schema name from the object SQL-Server-Authenticatoinname if it is equal to MetaDefSchema.

without setting, the automatic coder creates :
dbname.username.tablename  -> invalid object name

With setting MetaDefSchema to sqlserver-username :
dbname.tablename  -> works  !

See also the embarcadero-doc at :
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Connect_to_Microsoft_SQL_Server_(FireDAC)

Hope, it helps someone else..

regards, Lutz

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to create your migrations after writing the models

Answer (score 0):

For me I had rename from

```
[Database_LS].[schema].[TableView]
```

to

```
[Database_LS].[Database].[schema].[TableView]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on Azure SQL Server. For storing the data I used table values param
like

```
DECLARE @INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3 TABLE { 
     x int;
 }
```

I discovered the error in writing on the queries

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    [@INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3]
WHERE 
    [@INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3].[ConsentDefinitionId] = 3
```

While querying the columns, it's okay to wrap it with braces like `[@INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3].[ConsentDefinitionId]` but when referring to just the table valued param, there should be no params. So it should be used as  `@INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3`

So the code now must be changed to

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    @INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3
WHERE 
    [@INTERMEDIATE_TABLE3].[ConsentDefinitionId] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to alter a stored procedure that didn't exist in the database, after creating it and refreshing local cache, it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution turned to be changing the user/role that I was trying to query it with, because my role didn't have access to it.

As a side note: the error message was encountered during the replication through cdc.