# Sql Server management studio "Invalid Object name dbo.xxxxx"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a EmpDB and created a table "EmpTable" when I try to create a simple SP I am getting compile time error "Invalid Object name dbo.EmpTable" - why?

Following is the sql statements

```sql
use EmpDB;
Go
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetEmpNames

AS

SELECT * FROM dbo.EmpTable
```

Comment: Are you sure that the schema for your table is `dbo`?, what happens if you do `SELECT * FROM EmpTable`?

Comment: See this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1362531/292060

Answer (score 1):

I just created a test version and ran your script with any issues.

A few things to check:

If you run just the `SELECT` does it run?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.EmpTable
```

If not, then verify the schema the EmpTable is in and replace the dbo.

```
SELECT * FROM yourSchemaNameGoesHere.EmpTable
```

Make sure that your table that you created is in the correct database `EmpDB` and you didn't accidentally create your table in the wrong database.

Comment: yes, SELECT * FROM EmpTable works for me.I checked the table its right under EmpDB.

Comment: Yeah ......:) now its working there might be some DB refresh issue.After disconnect and connect its working.