# Invalid Object Name sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I keep getting an invalid object name error on my sql code. (`member_number, subscriber_policy_number`) is underlined with the error message.

The code itself runs fine with no errors, why does this happen? None of the code above this is highlighted

```
update smmdmm.aid_data
set Member_Number = Subscriber_Policy_Number
where Member_Number in ('000000000','000000001')
```

Comment: Which DBMS? Where do you see these *errors*?

Comment: Probably you need to refresh the intellisense cache assuming SSMS.

Comment: relational dbms using sql server management studio

Comment: tried a refresh of the intellisense cache, but had no impact

Comment: Had the same problem and refreshing intellisense cache as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list) worked for me in SSMS.

Comment: Don't forget to set user's default schema, if you have any schema over tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server invalid object name - but tables are listed in SSMS tables list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list)

Answer (score 38):

Make sure you're using the correct database.  It may be defaulting to the "Master" database, and it doesn't look like you have the full schema for the referenced table.

Ex:  `[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName]` or `[Database1].[smmdmm].[aid_data]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate you leaving this answer in this discussion.

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
```

Comment: "Ctrl + Shift + r" is a shortcut for this, as well.

Answer (score 15):

According to the error you're receiving I assume that you're using MSSQL.

at the beginning of your queries try:

```
use [YOUR_DATABASE_NAME];
```

and then your query. It helped in my case.

Comment: Nice and simple for a developer who doesn't use a DB in their normal course of work.  Works for me - thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me : Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache

Answer (score 2):

There might be 2 reasons for it.

1. Table name is wrong

   Sol: *Verify the table name and try to execute*
2. Database name and schema name are not mentioned with the table name in query

   Sol: *Mention the database and schema name in SQL query.*

For ex:

```
select * from MESQLDBM.dbo.Alert ([DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName])
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was missing `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me in a function and it was a table within that had been dropped long time ago

Answer (score 0):

I came to this page as I kept getting this error each time I ran the program, anyway I found that in the settings my SQL string table name was missing the underscore and should have been as follows; tbl_Customer.

Comment: Is this related to the question in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I faced case sensitivity problem. Below was my erroneous query

```
SELECT * FROM [bccci$Biochemical View] AS ibv
```

here `"V"`- 1st character of last part of table name is Upper case but in actual table name it was lower case. that is `[bccci$Biochemical view]`. So my correct code was

```
SELECT * FROM [bccci$Biochemical view] AS ibv
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode with the mssql plugin, many times the tables you create are not recognized as objects but it is not enough just to update the database.

You need to update the VSCode Intelissense cache.

To do this just close and open VSCode .

The other way is to type the command `ctrl+shift+p` , which will open the command palette and then type SQL and locate in the ***`MS SQL list: Refresh IntelisSense Cache`***