# yii2 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [(null)]

Tags: yii2

i'm try to connection with dblib in yii2 but if run code got error

> General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208]
>   (severity 16) [(null)]

what is problem?.. thanks

Comment: [error meaning](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1-500.aspx) and [may be solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621007/invalid-object-name-sql)