# Invalid Object Name DBTOOLUSERS

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2014

Okay I know there are a lot of questions regarding this issue but I can't seem to find a solution there. Plus a lot of them were using Hardcode queries but I am using xsd files to connect to the SQL server 2014. Following is the exception:

[image: Error that has been thrown by sqlconnector]

And this is my connection string:

`Data Source=NLNT832\SQLEXPRESS,2301;Initial Catalog=IPC_DATABASE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ipc_sp_user;Password=omr@n123`

I checked the table exists, so as the user. I can connect to the database, see the table in the list, run queries from xsd. But whenever I try to run it through C# it throws the above exception.

My C# code is something like this:

```
using (DSIPCDatabaseTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter queries = new DSIPCDatabaseTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter()) {
            queries.ChangeConnection(DBUtils.GetInstance.GetConnectionString);

            try
            {
                object o = queries.AddUser(textBox1.Text.ToString(), textBox2.Text.ToString(), comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
                if (o != null)
                    showOptionDialog();
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Insertion Error!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Below is the screenshot of the table present in the database and accessible by the username provided.[image: Table present in the database]

FYI I urge you to think twice before marking it as a duplicate.

Comment: you're going to have to provide more context than that in order to avoid it being flagged as a duplicate.  How is your situation any different than this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621007/invalid-object-name-sql ?

Comment: I did, please check again @sous2817

Comment: Where are you opening the connection?

Comment: You see the `DBUtils.GetInstance.GetConnectionString` it has the `GetInstance` function which calls the `connection.open()` @WEI_DBA

Comment: @TarekSaazeb, Thank you for clarifying. Can you show a screenshot of the database with the table? And you can see the table using the `ipc_sp_user` login, correct?

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions in the link I provided?  The first suggestion seems promising (Make sure you're using the correct database. It may be defaulting to the "Master" database, and it doesn't look like you have the full schema for the referenced table.).  Is AddUser a method your wrote?  If so, perhaps you should post that method as well...

Comment: See the link [link] (http://imgur.com/em0AzKA) @WEI_DBA

Comment: @sous2817 it's an insert query, yes I wrote the query. Do you have any experience using database tables through XSD? Please see the screenshot I provided.

Comment: Alright, nevermind guys, I found the solution already. Putting USE "MY_DATABASE_NAME" solved it. But I don't know why. Because as you can see I have other functions as well in `QueriesTableAdapter` and I didn't have to use this. @sous2817 and @WEI_DBA Btw, I get the same error while running a stored procedure. And I still can't solve it.