# Renaming column in SQL Server Express - Entity Framework can't find it

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, sql-server-express

I have an ASP.NET MVC web app using Entity Framework.
After deploying I decided to rename a column for consistency reasons.  I fixed it in the EF model and the local database that the model is based on. Since publish to filesystem can't update the database, I fixed it by hand in the SQL Server Express database on the destination server.

But the web app gets an error saying "Invalid column name 'LastUpdateTime'." (which is what I renamed it to).  I can see in SQL Server Express that the column *is* there and that is how it's spelled.

I copied the query from the web app log and ran it directly against the database. It worked but I was getting the red squiggly lines under LasUpdateTime.  I found this stackexchange article [sql server invalid object name - but tables are listed in SSMS tables list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list?rq=1), and following the answer there, the red squiggly lines went away, but the web app still gets the error.

Here's the query as EF created it.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[IsPrivate] AS [IsPrivate], 
    [Extent1].[LastUpdateTime] AS [LastUpdateTime], 
    [Extent1].[ThumbnailPhoto_Id] AS [ThumbnailPhoto_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Groups] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[LastUpdateTime] DESC
```

When I run this in a query in SQL Server, it works just fine, but the web app fails.

Out of curiosity, I just tried renaming the Description column to "blah".  The web app only complained about LastUpdateTime.

I suspected the Connection String was pointing to a copy of the original .mdb file, but it's pointing to the SQLEXPRESS server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest if you are using DATABASE first approach then the easiest way to drop table from the model and re-create it again or update the model from the update EF model option.

Comment: Even though you checked the connection string you're clearly not running against the right database. Did you check the right config file?

Comment: @GertArnold There's only one web.config, so I don't know where else it could be getting it from if there is. I know it's using the connection string, because I initially had problems when I changed it to connect to the server. It does *feel* like it's still using the original .mdf file though so you may be onto something