# Trouble referencing another SQL Server instance from a stored procedure (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, external-data-source

I have a view in my local db that references tables in another instance of SS (same physical server). It works perfectly. However, when I copy and paste the SQL from the view to a stored procedure, the table objects are not recognized.  For e.g., rolling over a table reference in the FROM clause throws the pop-up:

> Invalid object name 'AFIRALSRV06.AFI.dbo.RECEIVABLE'.

I am dbo on both databases/instances and logged in with windows authentication.

Also, the AFIRALSRV06 server is a linked server in my local database. This was set up before I got here 3 weeks ago, so could that link be creating a conflict? There are no logins configured in the linked server properties. But, as I said executing the query as a view works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that only when you are [hovering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1362531/11683) over the table name in the editor, or when you are trying to save the procedure too?

Comment: Does the stored procedure run, though? Microsoft's native Intellisense doesn't always acknowledge linked server objects. There's a good chance this is just an SSMS issue, not a real issue.

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2013** version - there's 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and soon 2019 - so which one **are you** using??

Comment: All I've done so far is to rt-click on Stored Procedures > Add New, and pasted my view's sql between BEGIN-END.  I stopped there because I got the red squigglies under my fully qualified table names.  This is the first time I've tried to reference tables in another instance and I guess you're saying to ignore the messages and try to run the sp.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Comment: marc-s, maybe you can tell me what version this is.  I just started working here, and didn't recognize the version in the connection name.

Comment: Connection name:  AFIRALSRV06\DEV(SQL Server 13.0.4522.0 - ACCUFAB\bcanavan)

Comment: That's [SQL Server 2016](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). Run SELECT @@VERSION if you're curious.

Comment: And yes, for the moment, ignore the squiggles and try to proceed. I'm going to guess you'll be just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  You all have a been a big help.  I'll get back to you with results.

Comment: Incidentally, the sp was created with no errors.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I just needed to ignore the "invalid object name" error.  The sp saved with no problems, and my app is pulling the data from the sp perfectly.  Thanks again!