# "Invalid object name" error on INSERT to SQL Server from pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, insert, pyodbc

I am trying to insert some data into a SQL Server database using the pyodbc module.

I have the connection string working.

The following code lists the two columns in the table.

```
 for row in cursor.columns(table='InvUtil'):
     print (row.column_name)
```

I see the following two columns that are in the InvUtil table:

`server`

`termss`

I then try to insert data with the following command:

```
 cursor.execute("INSERT INTO InvUtil(server, termss) values (?, ?)", 'ten', 'eleven')
```

I get the following error.  Seems like it's having issues with the InvUtil table name.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SQLpydobc.py", line 61, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO InvUtil(server, termss) values (?, ?)", 'ten', 'eleven')
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]**Invalid object name 'InvUtil'**. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

I expect the script to run without errors.  I have a commit command later in the script so should see data in the columns.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list/1362575#1362575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps specify the full table name with schema/db as in `dbo.InvUtil`?

Or perhaps specify the default database name in the connection string (`Database=dbo` or `InitialCatalog=dbo`).

Comment: You were correct.  The system was defaulting to a different schema.  When the table was recreated with the "dbo" schema my python script worked.