# How to avoid invalid object name error while creating stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, mssql-jdbc

I have created two stored procedure from a single table:

Database name : sampleDemo

```
USE sampleDemo
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE employeeList    
    @city VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        emp_id, emp_dob
    FROM 
        employee
    WHERE 
        emp_city = @city
    ORDER BY 
        emp_id
END;
```

This one working completely fine but the other one:

```
USE sampleDemo
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE sp_listofemp 
    @city VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT emp_id, emp_name, emp_city, emp_dob
    FROM employee
    WHERE emp_city = @city
    ORDER BY emp_id
END;
```

Though both the procedure are almost same still the second one is throwing error

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure sp_listofemp, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Invalid object name 'sp_listofemp'

Can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ALTER PROC` only works with existing procedures. It sounds like the second one doesn't exist yet. Also, [best avoid `sp_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments): "Avoid the use of the sp_ prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql server invalid object name - but tables are listed in SSMS tables list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list)

Comment: As of SQL Server **2016 SP1** or newer, you can use `CREATE OR ALTER (procedurename)` to handle both cases - `CREATE` in case the stored procedure doesn't exist yet, `ALTER` if it does - in a single command

Comment: as the SP was not present, that's why it was throwing invalid object . Now I have changed it to CREATE and it's working. Thanks all