# SQL:What is the message "invalid object name" mean?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, intellisense

How can I disappear this error also he is run very well

[this what i can't understand what this error show if code run well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U10dk.png)

Comment: Press Ctrl+Shift+R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql server invalid object name - but tables are listed in SSMS tables list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list)

Comment: Sometimes this happened  after changing the database table and you need to refresh the IntelliSense by Ctrl + Shift + R

Answer (score 1):

It just means the intellisense in SQL management studio isn't up to date with all your table names etc. If there was a real error it would show when you try to run the code.

You can press Ctrl+Shift+R to get intellisense to refresh with all the latest information about your schema.

Comment: Thanks Bro for your help that make the error gone

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your queries execute, but the IntelliSense needs to be refreshed. 
CTRL + SHIFT + R should solve this.

Also discussed here: [Invalid Object name but tables are listed in ssms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list)

Comment: thanks all that make error gone thanks again