# Why queries won't work even though connection with database is ok?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created database in SQL Server Management Studio.
My connection with database is ok,  but query I try to execute is causing problems. It throws me "Invalid object name 'tw__towar'". Even though the query is working fine when I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Here is code fragment responsible for connection.

```
try {
        Class.forName(ssmsDriver);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, userPassword);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: connected to the database");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: class not found", e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: sql exception", e);
    }
```

And here is code responsible for executing query. Double underscore intended.

```
try {
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT tw_nazwa FROM tw__towar" +
                        " WHERE tw_ean='5903206038608';");
                mItemNameTextView.setText("SUCCESS");   // DELETE THIS LATER

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                mItemNameTextView.setText(e.getMessage());  // DELETE THIS LATER
            }
```

Does anybody have any idea what may be causing problem?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Please give schema name with table name . Here "SELECT tw_nazwa FROM [schema_name].tw__towar" + " WHERE tw_ean='5903206038608';"

Comment: @Stultuske error message is "Invalid object name 'tw__towar'"

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Here is screenshot of what I hope is what you asked for: https://postimg.cc/Ty32DZTg

Comment: Can you run this command in DB? SELECT '['+SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'].['+name+']'
AS SchemaTable
FROM sys.tables

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Yes, it returned me 4 records. First 3 are my tables, and the last one is [dbo].[sysdiagrams]

Comment: Can you paste the output here?

Comment: SchemaTable
[dbo].[tw__towar]
[dbo].[uz__uzytkownik]
[dbo].[tw_termin]
[dbo].[sysdiagrams]

Comment: Okay do write this is your query please  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT tw_nazwa FROM dbo.tw__towar" +
                        " WHERE tw_ean='5903206038608' ");

Comment: Unfortunately it gives similar result, which is: "Invalid object name 'dbo.tw__towar'".

Comment: Please check this link once if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, so I'll post answer here for anyone that would have the same issue in the future.

The problem was that I tried to operate on the sa account (system administrator). I could connect to database but it cut off my access to tables.

To solve this problem you need to create new login by:

- right-click on "Security" folder in object explorer
- select New -> Login
- enter your new login
- check "SQL Server authentication" and set your password
- I unchecked "Enforce password expiration"
- Go to "Server Roles" which is on the left side of this window and check "dbcreator"
- Click OK, and restart program.
- Login with new credentials and check if everything works.

I hope it will help someone in the future.