# Transact SQL with Liquibase

Tags: t-sql, liquibase

We use Liquibase for our DB management. I am trying to use the non-2005 script from https://blog.devart.com/find-invalid-objects-in-your-databases.html page to find invalid objects in our database.

The whole T-SQL works fine in SSMS but fails when run through liquibase. Error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name '#objects'.
```

My Changelog has definition as:

```
<changeSet id="Repetitive" author="XXXXXX" runAlways="true">
        <sqlFile splitStatements="false"
                 path="scripts/repetitive/check_invalid_objects.sql"/>
    </changeSet>
```

I have even tried with various combinations of usage of `GO` and its placement in the script but it fails for something or the other.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Midhun

Comment: This is an interesting situation. Were you able to get it sorted? Can you post what you did to resolve it? TY

Comment: I was thinking more about this and trying to research it. I came across this article about resolving this error and it might help - but since you're getting the error when you run Liquibase specifically, I'm not 100% sure it'll be a complete fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362531/sql-server-invalid-object-name-but-tables-are-listed-in-ssms-tables-list